# Determining "Truthiness" of an expression?

Tags: ruby, truthiness

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Check if Ruby object is a Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028243/check-if-ruby-object-is-a-boolean)
>   [How can I avoid truthiness in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645232/how-can-i-avoid-truthiness-in-ruby)

Given an array like the following (for example):

```
[3, false, "String", 14, "20-31", true, true, "Other String"]
```

Is there an easier way to determine which elements are *actual* boolean values without resorting to this, for example?

```
value === TrueClass || value === FalseClass
```

Relying on the position in the array is not an option, as it will vary from case-to-case.

Comment: Makes me wonder why there isn't a `Boolean` class that `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` inherit from...

Comment: aha - thanks guys. voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `(true & value) == value`.  The part in parentheses seems to always return a boolean; if the value wasn't originally a bool, then it won't be equal to the result.  A bool, however, will.

Comment: Slightly simpler way is to use a double negative, ie: `!!value`. For example: `[!!true, !!false, !!nil, !!0] => [true, false, false, true]`

Comment: @KristianHoldhus: `!!value == value` does look less clunky.  (Still need the `== value` part, though, since the point is to make sure boolifying the value didn't change it.)