# What method is called to evaluate Fixnum equality?

Tags: ruby

I know that in Ruby, all numbers, including zero, evaluate to true when used in a conditional statement. However, what method is being called to perform this evaluation (see Ex. 2 below)? I thought it might be the == operator, but not so as they return opposite results.

- Example 1: The equality method evaluates zero to false

  ```
  >> puts "0 is " << (0 == true ? "true" : "false")
  0 is false
  ```
- Example 2: Yet zero alone evaluates to true, because it is not nil

  ```
  >> puts "0 is " << (0 ? "true" : "false") 
  0 is true
  ```

Comment: also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645232/how-can-i-avoid-truthiness-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't "evaluate to true" in the sense of being equal the object `true`. All objects except `nil` and `false` are *considered to be logically true* when they're the value of a condition. This idea is sometimes expressed by saying they are *truthy*.

So, yes, testing equality uses the `==` operator. A bare `0` is truthy for the same reason `29` and `"Hi, I'm a string"` are truthy — it's not `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 == true # evaluates to false => ergo "false"
```

vs

```
0 # bare zero before the ? is evaluated using ruby truthiness and since it is not false or nil, "true" is returned
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "ruby truthiness"? Where is this implemented in the language? For example, how would one override it just as one could override the == operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645232/how-can-i-avoid-truthiness-in-ruby

Comment: Though I would not recommend overriding it, as you would get unexpected behavior in other people's code you depend on.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I understand that overriding is ill-advised when coding as usual. I'm looking at this for academic purposes, for the moment.